# How to find similar rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a table with entries like this in one column of one table:

```
"Vanity Counter Detail Luxury Collection"
"Vanity Counter Collection"
```

How would I write a select query to find all items that are similar but not exactly the same, perhaps searching the first two words?

*by the way the query can't be something literal ie. "like Vanity%' where I have to manually type in the search terms in the like statement of the query, I need it to do this with all items in the table (compare all items for similar items) OR if the query can accept a variable that I set earlier that would be fine as well.

eg. something like

```
set @myVar := (
  select filetitle 
  from 'table' where id=10880
);

select filetitle 
from 'table' 
where filetitle LIKE CONCAT('%', @myVar, '%');
```

But this doesn't work, it only finds the exact string of the original item, not similar items...

@myVar may return something like "Vanity Counter Detail Luxury Collection" for example.

I've tried using soundex and things...but I'm still very novice when it comes to mysql.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need some sort of definition of what it means to be "similar". Does it share more than 1 word? Does that make it similar? Does the 2 words it share must be adjacent? Once you have a rigorous definition of what it means to be similar, then you can construct a script that finds it based on that definition.

Comment: I mean like a algorithm that rates how similar and uses anything greater than 80% for example, but I can also work with something that simply compares the first X words.